# Weight of adjoint action on a lower central series extension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, arithmetic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a unipotent Lie $\mathbb{Q}_p$-group scheme, whose associated gradeds from the lower central series filtration are $\mathcal{U}_0 = \mathcal{U}^{\text{ab}}$, $\mathcal{U}_1 = [\mathcal{U},\mathcal{U}]$, and $\mathcal{U}_n = 0$ for all $n\ge 2$. That is, $\mathcal{U}$ is given by an extension of an abelian $\mathbb{Q}_p$-vector group by an abelian $\mathbb{Q}_p$-vector group, of the form:

$$1\longrightarrow \mathcal{U}_1\longrightarrow \mathcal{U}\longrightarrow \mathcal{U}_0\longrightarrow 1.$$

Now, since $\mathcal{U}_1$ is normal in $\mathcal{U}$, there is an associated adjoint action of $\mathcal{U}_0$ on $\mathcal{U}_1$. That is, there exists a representation $\rho: \mathcal{U}_0\longrightarrow \text{GL}(\mathcal{U}_1)$, and my question is: without any further assumptions on the extension, is it possible to say something about the weights of the adjoint action? Alternatively, is there some cohomological criterion which may be checked at the level of $\mathcal{U}, \mathcal{U}_0$ or $\mathcal{U}_1$, that would give us information about these weights, or if the action is pure, for example.

Thanks in advance!